# 5 random numbers. How does if(arr.indexOf(randnum) > -1) continue; prevent duplication?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I am creating an `array` with 5 random numbers that do not duplicate for the power-ball. I understand most of this block but I am still a noob and I don't fully understand how the `if(arr.indexOf(randnum) > -1) continue;`  prevents duplication.

Any explanation would be much appreciated.

```
let arr = [];
while(arr.length < 5){
    let randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 69) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(randnum)> -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randnum;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: [#Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is a good place to start.

Comment: I think the the explanation and visualization tool will help you to understand what is going under the hood. Just  post your JS code on `Javascript` box and then click `Forward >` to see what is happening each and every step here at http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=display

Comment: `arr.indexOf(randnum) > -1` means arr already has an element with value `randnum`, `continue` means skip current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

arr.indexOf(randnum) finds the index of the number "randnum" in the array "arr":

For example [2,5,7,11,6].indexOf(7) == 2 because the number 7 is in the second position.

it returns -1 when the number is not found: [2,5,7,11,6].indexOf(8) == -1

Checking if it is greater than -1 is actually a check whether "randnum" is in the array "arr".

Answer (score 0):

so, basically
**array.indexOf** --> if the element exists, it will return it's index, if not it will return -1.

**continue** means, ignore the rest of the code inside the loop and start another iteration in the loop.

**if(arr.indexOf(randnum)> -1) continue;**  means, if index of element is greater that -1, which means element has been found, then continue, means don't execute that line 
**arr[arr.length] = randnum;**

Comment: This definitely helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to break apart the function to better understand how it works is to set a lower range of possible values. In the example below, the values 1-5 are possible. If you run the snippet below, you will be able to see when duplicate values are detected.

`arr.indexOf(randnum) > -1` detects if the value for `randnum` exists within the array. When a value exists in the array, a value greater than -1 is returned by the function. Otherwise, -1 is returned to indicate that it does not exist in the array.

If the above evaluates to true, `continue` will execute, which skips `arr[arr.length] = randnum;`, which is responsible for adding the new number to the array.

```js
let arr = [];
while (arr.length < 5) {
  let randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  if (arr.indexOf(randnum) > -1) {
    console.log("Duplicate detected: " + randnum);
    console.log("Current array values: " + arr);
    continue;
  }
  arr[arr.length] = randnum;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: so basically it is saying that if a random number is already in the array do not add a new number and loop back through until the random number has not been in the array? And once a random number has not been in the array it will add the new number with  arr[arr.length] = randnum; ?